# firebase nodejs server and gcloud storage--get metadata

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage

for the correct security of my app i have been obliged to set up a small nodejs server for firebase, but the problems are not over.... the firebase server sdk not support the storage apis. i read that for this is neccessary a gcloud storage apis because firebase use the same service.

in the server side is important to get a files custom metadata because i must read and update they. i not find the apposite functions to get a file metadata. in the client sdk is simple

```
// Create a reference to the file whose metadata we want to retrieve
var forestRef = storageRef.child('images/forest.jpg');

// Get metadata properties
forestRef.getMetadata().then(function(metadata) {
  // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});
```

and in gcloud storage what function can i use?? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [getMetadata()](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.36.0/storage/file?method=getMetadata) method in [gcloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node):

```
var gcloud = require('gcloud');

// Initialize GCS
var gcs = gcloud.storage({
  projectId: 'my-project',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});

// Reference an existing bucket
var bucket = gcs.bucket('foo.appspot.com');

// Reference to a file
var file = bucket.file('path/to/my/file');

// Get the file metadata
file.getMetadata(function(err, metadata, apiResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(metadata);
  }
});
```